# DRF - CreateAPIView Nested Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I've an interesting question and want expert views on it.

I've the following models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = ForeignKey(B)
    c = ForeignKey(B)
    d = ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class C(models.Model):
    pass

class D(models.Model):
    pass
```

Following are my serializers:

```
class ASearializer(serializers.Serializer):
    b = BSearializer()
    c = CSearializer()
    d = DSearializer()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('b', 'c', 'd')

    def create(self, data):
        # I create the instance of A, B, C and D.
        return instance_of_A

class BSearializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'

class CSearializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = '__all__'

class DSearializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = D
        fields = '__all__'
```

My views:-

```
class View(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Aserializer
    queryset = A.object.all().select_related('b').select_related('c').select_related('d')
```

Everything works as expected. The request and the response works correctly.

However, the queries fired are not the way it was expected. While returning the data, DRF fires 3 extra queries to filter B, C and D, thereby ignoring the queryset.

**1) How to make DRF fire one single JOIN query?**

Comment: The View in your example is a CreateApiView, this mean that no list is returned. I've debugged with django debug toolbar, and I found 4 query for the 4 insertion. If I switch to a ListView, than the select_related do their job, and I found that a single query is fired.

Comment: ListAPIView does not support POST request

Comment: If you want support the creation and the list, you can use `ListCreateAPIView`. Here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views you can find all the existing classes and mixins to support the different request actions.

Comment: You didn't understand my question.

Comment: I try to reproduce your case but i see only 3 insert into and, before the session update query 3 weird SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count".